# How to delete an Environment Variable from inside a Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a Windows cmd batch file which will take an environment variable as a parameter and remove that Environment variable from the current cmd shell.

Setup the Environment variable BINGO

`SET BINGO=SHAZAM`

I can Remove the Environment variable Bingo from the command line like this:

`SET "BINGO="`

but from inside a batch file passing the environment variable's name as a parameter

`SET "%1="`

doesn't remove the variable in the calling cmd shell?   Is there a way to do this?

I'm also using

`SETX %1 ""`

`REG DELETE HKCU\Environment /F /V %1`

Inside my batch file to remove persistant environment variables.
These seem to work for getting rid of the environment variable from the registry but I can't remove it from the current cmd shell.

Comment: `set "%1="` works correctly as long as your script does not start with `setlocal`, which instantiates a local scope. If you open a command prompt and run `unset.bat bingo`, where unset.bat is just the one line `set "%~1="`, then `%bingo%` will not be set once the script is complete. However, if you close the command prompt and open a new one, `%bingo%` will be set again if it is a system variable because that's how system variables work. (But you didn't ask about system variables, so I digress.)

Comment: @SomethingDark,   Thank you.   And since I was using SETLOCAL your fix didn't work until I did an ENDLOCAL before the call.  Thanks you very much.  Thank you on the heads up for SETLOCAL.

Comment: keep in mind, `set` modifies the current locale (process or setlocal/endlocal instance) only, but not the system wide context, while `setx` modifies the system wide context only but not the current locale.

Comment: @Stephan,  yes if it wasn't clear I did the ENDLOCAL before the call to [ set "%~1=" ] command to kill the local variable from the current cmd shell from within a batch file.  I also did [ setx %1="" ]  to clear the environment var in the registry, and finally [ REG DELETE HKCU\Environment /F /V %1 ] to remove it from the registry